# dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_thread_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am attempting to set up my Rails database with `rake db:setup` and am getting the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_thread_select
  Referenced from: /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_thread_select
  Referenced from: /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have postgresql-9.6.1 installed., and my bundle install completes successfully.  (ran `gem pristine --all --extensions` as suggested [here](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issues/184/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not))

Has anyone been able to get around this problem?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$ bundle update pg --minor
```

--or--

```
$ bundle update pg --patch
```

--or--

```
$ bundle update pg
```